# Copy Azure Resources to client azure account

Tags: azure, deployment, copy, resources

We are working on following within Azure portal

- Azure Functions
- Data Factory
- Logic Apps
- Storage account (not files)

Now as we are done with development, we need to deploy these azure resources in client's UAT environment

I looked around (might be missing something) and found that deployment of Azure resources is not straightforward.

In Azure, it is like another subscription, correct?

So found this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuregov/2016/12/09/copying-azure-resource-groups-between-different-azure-subscriptions-or-environments/), which works with different PowerShell scripts to copies from one subscription to another

This is the right approach? & it cover everything required for resources to execute flawless (I still need to go thru scripts) for e.g. permissions, Data Factory datasets, etc?

Any other way to deploy (kind of export & import)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you need is to create a reusable arm template, your question lacks some details yet ARM templates are the way of automated deployment in Azure, on a high-level
start by authoring your arm template to deploy the vanilla required resources look here

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites/functions
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.datafactory/factories
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.logic/integrationaccounts
4. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.datalakeanalytics/accounts/storageaccounts

you can combine all of them in one big template using ARM template dependency and other functions 
look here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions

after you finish ARM templates can be used in many ways including PowerShell, direct API calls or even you can create a deployment in Azure and save it to be reused with a click
look here, also if there will be a high volume of users consider adding it to market place.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/

after finishing your implementation of vanilla resources you can then move into adding any customization you might have. 
this is the right and best way to do "afaik"

also look here to see all of your existing resources in an arm template view 
https://resources.azure.com/
my understanding of Azure is that almost everything with some few exceptions has an ARM template representation

hope this would help.